# Selection of reactive values in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a small query in Shiny. I developed an app which would call/source scripts based on user selection in drop down and the called scripts would create a forecast variable as a time series, another time series(containing the actual values along with values of regressors) and a variable containing the MAPE value of the forecast. I have built 2 outputs( both renderDygraph ) where I would provide the forecast and the actual time series values separately. The code I have written is as below

```
server <- function(input, output) {
test <- function(var){

switch(var,
       "5184-7740" = source("5184-7740.R"),
       "5184-8554" = source("5184-8554.R"))
}
f1 <- reactive({
test(input$state)  
forecast # Contains the forecast values
})

f2 <- reactive({
test(input$state)  
rr # Contains the actual time series along with regressors
})

output$plot1<-renderDygraph ({
dygraph(dd(), main = "Inventory Level Forecasts") %>%
dyRangeSelector() %>%  
dyAxis("y", label = "Inventory Level in Millions")
}) 

output$plot2<-renderDygraph ({
dygraph(dd2(), main = "Actual Time Series") %>%
dyOptions(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, "Set2")) %>%
dyAxis("y", label = "Quantity in Millions")

})
}
```

Now my query is, is it possible to call both forecast and rr from a single reactive expression. Because currently, it is executing twice and calling the same script twice for each output plot. Is there any way I can define a single reactive statement and call forecast variable and the actual time series using some statements( eg: f1$forecast and f1$rr, but $ doesnt work). I am planning to dynamically show MAPE value also so I would define a renderText block, but I dont want to again source the same script in reactive expression just for getting the MAPE variable. I hope I have explained my issue clearly, kindly let me know if the problem is not clear enough. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f1 <- reactive({
    test(input$state)  
    list(forecast = forecast, rr = rr) 
})
```